# Getting a problem in Media Player Library in android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I was trying to make a music app which loads Song Url , Song name and Artist name from firebase. I've two activities one is ExtrasActivity .ExtrasActivity contain a recyclerview which loads song in list and when we click on item then it sends songUrl , SongName , and ArtistName to another activity which was named as StackActivity. I am getting problem in StackActivity like when song is playing and if i back click and play another song then sometimes it works fine but sometimes it play two songs together.
I tried many things to solve this problem but none of them working properly I think there is a problem in my StackActivity.

Here is my StackActivity:-

```
public class StackActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Boolean isPlaying = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stack_activity_name);

        SeekBar Song_playing_seekbar;

        TextView songInfoSong = findViewById(R.id.song_info_song);
        TextView songInfoArtist = findViewById(R.id.song_info_artist);

        songInfoSong.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Name"));
        songInfoArtist.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Artist"));

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        playSong();

    }

    private void playSong() {
        final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("SongUrl"));

        storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                try {


                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    final String url = uri.toString();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(StackActivity.this);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.i("TAg", "aFailed");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        CheckIfSongIsPlayingOrNot();

        if (isPlaying == false) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } else if (isPlaying == true) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }

    }

    private void CheckIfSongIsPlayingOrNot() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            isPlaying = true;
        } else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            isPlaying = false;
        }
    }
```

So if you find any problem please help me to improve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the `MediaPlayer` being recreated everytime you start the `StackActivity`. I even wonder why this does not happen everytime. To be more precisely the old `MediaPlayer` instance is never stopped or even more important released. You should take a closer look into the [MediaPlayer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) to understand the states.

But for this specific case I would try to define a MediaPlayer [Singleton](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/).

```java
public class MediaPlayerSingleton implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    private static MediaPlayerSingleton instance = null;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    private MediaPlayerSingleton() {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    }

    public static MediaPlayerSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MediaPlayerSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {   
        resume();
    }

    /**
     * This will load the given URL into the media player.
     * @param url The URL string from the Firebase Uri.
     */
    public void play(String url) {  
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset()
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public void resume() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    public void release() {
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

You can then use this in your StackActivity.

```java
public class StackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // your onCreate() but leave out the MediaPlayer references

    private void playSong() {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("SongUrl"));

        storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                MediaPlayerSingleton.getInstance().play(uri.toString());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.i("TAg", "aFailed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But be sure to call the `release()` function of this singleton in your starting activity's `onDestroy()` (for example `ExtrasActivity`) like this:

```java
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    MediaPlayerSingleton.getInstance().release();
}
```

This has to be done to free memory.

Just a side note on the singleton example I provided. It's just a simple example that could be improved e.g. with extra null checks for the MediaPlayer instance. But it should give you a little base.

Comment: sorry for saying this can you please update my code?

Comment: but there is a problem when I click back and play another song then it does not play next song it play only 1 song

Comment: Do you mean it stops playing entirely when you go back and click another song?

Comment: I want to make a function like when I click song on ExtrasActivity then it send songUrl Songplayingactivity and If I click back and play next song then it stop previous song and play new song like Spotify

Comment: I updated the code. Now it should stop the previous song and start loading the new song and play it afterwards.

Comment: I tried it and your code stop previous song but doesn't play new song please help

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot the state rules. I updated the code to use `reset()` so that a new data source could be set.

Comment: it works successfully but I have a question I want to control music with seekbar can I do that if yed can you tell me how and if no can you tell me another way?

Comment: Yes this should be possible. But please take a look at the `MediaPlayer` docs. This will help you to understand `MediaPlayer` and therefore you'll be able to fix future problems mainly on your own :)

Comment: please help me sir